# Running inspectdb on a specific schema

Tags: django, postgresql

I'd like to use [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) in order to build corresponding models for freshly introduced tables.  But is looks like this command only looks up the `public` schema, while the new tables are in another one.

Is it possible to specify a schema to `inspectdb` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/cbess/1031701), I modified `django.core.management.commands.inspectdb`: around line 32, in `handle_inspection()`, after `cursor = connection.cursor()`, add `cursor.execute("SET search_path TO myotherschema")`.

```
def handle_inspection(self, options):
    connection = connections[options.get('database')]

    table2model = lambda table_name: table_name.title().replace('_', '').replace(' ', '').replace('-', '')

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SET search_path TO myotherschema")
    # [...]
```

As of, at least, Django 1.9:

```
def handle_inspection(self, options):
    # [...]
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SET search_path TO myotherschema")
        # [...]
```

Comment: [This is now part of `django-extensions`](https://github.com/abourguignon/django-extensions/commit/573ae547862b173d00011e892c974b38b30dbc26)

Comment: Where in django-extensions?

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you have to specify the search_path, by adding an option in your DATABASES variable at settings.py, like that:

```
'OPTIONS': {
       'options': '-c search_path=myschema'
}
```

The full DATABASES variable should be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=myschema'
        }
    }
}
```

After that `python manage.py inspectdb` should work on your schema

Comment: specifying the 'search_path' is not changing its behaviour. It still imports from dbo schema only.

Answer (score 0):

may be simple way always is the best

you can change schma public to another name

login to database user interface and open query tools then run :
alter schema public rename to public2

then you can change the specifica schema name to public (whitch you need to collect django models form it)

then run this command on your text editor

```
python server/manage.py inspectdb  > models.py
```

then rename your schama again to the specific name was

Answer (score -1):

In the file **settings.py** add `SCHEMA_TO_INSPECT = 'myschema'` and `inspectdb` would search in the specified schema

P.S. This is and old post, so I use this solution to inspect a DB with DJango without modify any of the suggested files and it worked for me. Regards

Comment: Could you please provide a link or another point to that specific settings variable?

Comment: @9769953 I see some old posts like this one. All solutions I read, suggest to modify some internal DJango files. Then I saw this code in the internal files:
´return getattr(settings, 'SCHEMA_TO_INSPECT', 'dbo')´ 
and I realize that the schema is taken from the Settings, so putting the value in the settings allow me to use inspect DB with desired schema. I don't know why someone down vote mi answer.