# How do i inspect all tables in databes mssql by Django inspect

Tags: sql-server, django, inspect

I have mssql database with few tables:

```
[dbo].[one_table]
[dbo].[two_table]
[model].[three_table]
[model].[four_table]
[plan].[five_table]
```

my django settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "NAME": "ips_db",
        "USER": "sa",
        "PASSWORD": "***",
        "HOST": "***",
        "PORT": "1433",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        },
    },
}
```

When i try inspect db by

```
python inspectdb > models.py
```

I get only `one_table` and `two_table`

```
class One_table(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(db_column='FirstName', max_length=30, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')  # Field name made lowercase.
    lastname = models.CharField(db_column='LastName', max_length=40, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'One_table'


class Two_table(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(db_column='Test', max_length=10, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tes2 = models.CharField(db_column='Tes2', max_length=10, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Two_table'
```

How can i get all tables models from my database???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running inspectdb on a specific schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986917/running-inspectdb-on-a-specific-schema)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at mssql\introspection.py.
There is Databaseintrospection.get_table_list(). Sql query in this method is

```
sql = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ' + "'" + get_schema_name() + "'"
```

and i look at the `get_schema_name()` and...
that is

```
def get_schema_name():
    return getattr(settings, 'SCHEMA_TO_INSPECT', 'dbo')
```

Cause i just delete `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA"` and get all my tables.
This looks like very strange. I can`t choose schema.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t this problem. Just write each table by comma separated

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).